# How to use the splitted sub array of an array after using array.split() method in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

1. I want to convert my image into a numpy array
2. and then split this array into two arrays (so that left half of image goes to one array and right half to other).
3. I want to count the non zero elements of these two arrays and compare with each other and give a boolean output.

What I cant figure out is **how to use these two arrays** so that i can **count these non zero elements of each array**?

Here is my code until now:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

Image = Image.open('myimage.jpg')
array = np.array(Image)
split = np.split(array,2,0)      //code is working fine until this point
```

Comment: Avoid naming variables the same thing as modules, functions, and methods (i.e. `im = Image.open(...)` and `arr = np.array(im)`).  With these changes, your code runs fine for me on a sample image.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `np.split(array, 2, 0)` you split it into two arrays vertically, so you'll get the upper half and the lower half.  You want to split along axis `1` to get left and right: `np.split(array, 2, 1)`.

Second, `np.split` returns *two* arrays if you split into two, and they're stored in a list.  If you want the first one, use `split[0]` and if you want the second, use `split[1]`, or if you want to unpack them at once:

```
left, right = np.split(array, 2, 1)
```

Now, to count nonzero elements, you have to define "element," more carefully, because a jpg image has three elements per pixel.  If you want elements, just use:

```
lcount = np.count_nonzero(left)
```

If you want pixels, you'll have to convert to grayscale somehow.  Here's one way:

```
grey = np.asarray(im.convert('L'))
lgray, rgray = np.split(grey, 2, 1)
lcount = np.count_nonzero(lgrey)
```

I would also rewrite the beginning a little because you don't want to use `Image` since that's already the name of the module from `PIL`:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('myimage.jpg')  # don't name something Image, the module is Image.
arr = np.array(im)
left, right = np.split(arr, 2, 1)
```

Comment: +1.  Also, my first impression was that OP might be looking for something like `np.where(lgray != rgray[:,::-1])` (i.e. testing symmetry of the image), but asked in a weird way.